# Is it possible to aggregate information from portal list to My Site

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

Is it possible to aggreagate information from a list in a sitecollection and/or a portal site to "My Site"?

I would like to display all my calendar appointments made in the portal (or sub-site collection) in a webpart under "My Site"

Comment: Third party  tool like SharePoint List Collection(http://www.sharepointboost.com/listcollection.html) can do that.
What more I think there are several blog which provides code with which you can get it down without payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a calendar roll-up web part.  There are several 3rd party tools out there that do this.  Companies that come to mind first are CorasWorks and Bamboo Solutions. (I am not endorsing either. :))  You might be able to find some free 3rd party roll-ups if you look hard enough.

If you have any sp devs, they could write this webpart for you with little effort.

I will see if I can find you a link or two.

Good Luck!

[Free List Rollup at CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/illustris/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16317)

http://www.corasworks.com/

http://www.bamboosolutions.com/

I have not tried the CodePlex rollup, but have tried both the corasworks and bamboo rollups.  If you can get the CodePlex rollup to do what you want, I would stick with that. :)